# React, Invalid value for prop `component` in Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have read another questions about this but in my situation I don't know how to handle it.
I got this warning:

Warning: Invalid value for prop `component` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.

```
<Link component={MyLink} to='/summary-upload-tco'>
  <Button>asdas</Button>}
</Link>
```

and

```
const MyLink = props => <Link to={props.to} {...props} />;
```

Is there a way then to pass the props `component` to  with that MyLink defined as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Link` component doesn't accept a `component` props. If you want to create your own custom `Link` you can just wrap it and use the `useRouteMatch` hook as a helper:

Example taken from [react-router's DOCS](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link)

```
// This example show how you could create a custom
// <Link> that renders something special when the URL
// is the same as the one the <Link> points to.

export default function CustomLinkExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <OldSchoolMenuLink
          activeOnlyWhenExact={true}
          to="/"
          label="Home"
        />
        <OldSchoolMenuLink to="/about" label="About" />

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function OldSchoolMenuLink({ label, to, activeOnlyWhenExact }) {
  let match = useRouteMatch({
    path: to,
    exact: activeOnlyWhenExact
  });

  return (
    <div className={match ? "active" : ""}>
      {match && "> "}
      <Link to={to}>{label}</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```